# Deprecation Notice - Elasticsearch - Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, database, elasticsearch

I have installed version 2.3.0 of Magento and I have received this notification:

> Deprecation Notice
>
> Catalog Search is currently configured to use the MySQL engine, which
>   has been deprecated. Consider migrating to one of the Elasticsearch
>   engines now to ensure there are no service interruptions during your
>   next upgrade.

My system is:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx 1.14.0
- MySQL 5.7.25

What should I do with this? It is important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog

Open **Catalog Search** and select **Elastic Search 5.0 +**
[image]
Flush Magento Cache , do a full reindex, and check again .

If you see Magento 2.3.0 release notes [LINK](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html) ,

If you still having issues than install Elastic Search 5.x with this steps magento provides [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html). It is easy , just follow the steps . This link [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/deb.html) has the steps for ubuntu .

> Elasticsearch is now the default search engine in Magento. MySQL
>   search has been deprecated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I had read that but I have to configure something on my Ubuntu server? or in my database? or should I just do that configuration that you tell me and nothing else?

Comment: Just do that configuration , do e cache clean && flush also a full reindex.

Comment: Your are welcome :). If you still having issues than install Elastic Search 5.x with this steps magento provides https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html . It is easy , just follow the steps . This link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/deb.html  has the steps for ubuntu .

Comment: I have problems with the install, could you help me?

Comment: I followed the installation steps but when I check the status of Elasticsearch, it gives me an error

Comment: I have opened this thread, in case you can help to me... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260673/problems-with-elasticsearch-install-ubuntu Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I find it quite irritating they are trying to phase out MySQL searching and forcing people to pay for a 3rd party service....Yes you do have to pay for it if you want it to work properly and be secure.... The free version of elasticsearch lets anyone query sensitive customer data from your website. If you want to add security, you must pay for gold or platinum elasticsearch service.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-security-configure-tls-ssl-pki-authentication

For me personally I will just refrain from upgrading Magento when MySQL searching officially gets phased out. I'm sitting at Magento 2.3.1.

Comment: I'm agree with you, finally, I'm using the SQL searching... But I'm using Magento 2.3.1. Do you use any extension to speed up searches?

Comment: No I do not....However everything still seems to work pretty fast for me on the Gen4 VPS I got from GoDaddy.

Comment: If you install it on the same host, to begin with, it will run on a port that is not by default open in a firewall. So how is it insecure unless paid? Further, if you put it on a separate host, adding a TLS certificate and HTTP auth is merely a step to configuring it, so again how it is insecure unless paid? The cited article seems to mention the paid TLS feature of commercial Elasticsearch, but you can use any TLS terminator (=NGINX) with the freeware version, and that's what Magento itself [recommends](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-nginx.html)

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2.3 the option is here: [image]