# Problems with Elasticsearch install Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, database, nginx, elasticsearch, ubuntu

I have installed on my Magento 2.3 server and an annotation has arrived for me to install Elasticsearch. This is my system:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nginx 1.14.0
- MySQL 5.7.25

I have followed these instructions:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/deb.html

And this is the error that I have:

[image]

Comment: try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Magento Open Source 2.3.x supports the following Elasticsearch versions:

Elasticsearch 5.2
Elasticsearch 2.x

Comment: @Suman-PHP4U ok but, How do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

For OS relates issues check below post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447434/elasticsearch-memory-problems

Either give more memory to your VM, or change Elasticsearch JVM settings /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options and lower the values of the following parameters: -Xms512m -Xmx512m

Comment: My server is a digital ocean server with 2G of memory...

Comment: If you check the error log it says "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue" so you need to increase the JVM memory, talk to there customer care

Comment: You can change the allocations in the config.  On a dev server I only allow 200MB