# Magento2 Products backend keyword search is too slow after upgrade

Tags: magento2, catalog, backend, products-management

After we upgrade to magento 2.4.2, the keyword search is extremely slow on admin->catalog->products section. When we checked the DB, we could see some keys are dropped from the product tables. For example CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ROW_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID. Anybody has got similar issue and any recommended solution?

Comment: Have you configured elastic search credentials and config? Because Magento 2.4.x  have removed completely the mysql search.  [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260568/deprecation-notice-elasticsearch-magento-2-3-0)

Comment: Hi @VyacheslavShmal, the issue is not in storefront. It is on admin catalog->products grid and when try to search the product by entering something in the Keyword text box

Comment: @ManafPM Had you found anything related to this?

Comment: You should use the filters instead of the search box. If your catalog is big enough using the search box is a performance killer

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too with a Magento 2.4 shop with a big catalog (150.000 products).

ElasticSearch isn't used in the admin section, so the search runs against MySQL. It makes sense: we don't want to risk stale data due to an outdated index.

The slow response is due multiple queries (about 20) being fired against the DB by Magento. These 4 alone take a whopping 7.5 seconds on my server

```sql
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 4);
SELECT `d`.`option_id`, `o`.`attribute_id`, IFNULL(s.store_id, d.store_id) AS `store_id`, `a`.`frontend_input` FROM `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `d`
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `s` ON s.option_id = d.option_id AND s.store_id=2
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `o` ON o.option_id=d.option_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `a` ON o.attribute_id=a.attribute_id WHERE (d.store_id=0) AND (o.attribute_id IN (184, 160, 223, 201, 222, 183, 188, 185, 259, 186, 84, 181, 85, 182)) AND (IF(s.value_id > 0, s.value, d.value) LIKE '%bambini%');
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (`sku` LIKE '%bambini%') UNION ALL SELECT `t1`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t1`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id WHERE (t1.attribute_id IN (61, 62)) AND (t1.store_id = 0) AND (IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) LIKE '%bambini%') UNION ALL SELECT `t1`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t1`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id WHERE (t1.attribute_id IN (60, 86)) AND (t1.store_id = 0) AND (IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) LIKE '%bambini%')));
SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (`sku` LIKE '%bambini%') UNION ALL SELECT `t1`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t1`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id WHERE (t1.attribute_id IN (61, 62)) AND (t1.store_id = 0) AND (IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) LIKE '%bambini%') UNION ALL SELECT `t1`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t1`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id WHERE (t1.attribute_id IN (60, 86)) AND (t1.store_id = 0) AND (IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) LIKE '%bambini%')));
```

There are others which take 1-2 seconds each, so time adds up.

I recommended my store manager to expand the filter and search **by name** only.

Comment: Dr G Z Z Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.